# SPOT 6/7 conversion to BOA/Surface Reflectance

Tags: qgis-3, atmospheric-correction, reflectance, spot5

I am quite new to GIS and even newer to SPOT as an image source.  In general, all of the other sources I have used for analysis (Landsat 7 & 8, Sentinel-2) have been corrected to BOA reflectance prior to use.  However, I can't find any methodology for doing the same for SPOT 6/7.  Is it possible/advisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the [ESA archive for Spot](https://earth.esa.int/eogateway/missions/spot). The processing stage depends one the data product you use and which is not defined in your question. The Spot product palette is very rich and ranges from [panchromatic over mulit-spectral to panchromatic sharpened multi-spectral products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOT_(satellite)).

The [SPOTMaps 2.5 dataset](https://earth.esa.int/eogateway/catalog/spot-6-to-7-full-archive-and-tasking-and-spotmaps-2-5-dataset) for example has cite: *"SPOTMaps 2.5 is a dataset providing nationwide or regional seamless coverage, orthorectified, derived from colour imagery acquired by SPOT 5. It is available over more than 110 countries, representing a total of more than 95 million km2. The dataset has a resolution of 2.5 metres and it is composed by level 2A data with radiometric correction identical to that of level 1A."*.

At the bottom if the WEB page you will find a link called [SPOT 6&7 Imagery User Guide Product Specification](https://earth.esa.int/eogateway/documents/20142/37627/SPOT-6-7-imagery-user-guide.pdf).

Another overview for older SPOT products  can be found at the [Office for Outer Space Affairs in the UN-SPIDER Knowledge Portal -- SPOT Imagery (CNES)](https://www.un-spider.org/es/node/8727).